# How to request a random row in SQL with static one-time random

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

I know I can random by following:

```
SELECT column
FROM table
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

However, this will random data from all id each time when page load.

But I want it just random from id and freeze data without random from other id if I reload page again.

Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Perhaps sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Save the result in a session variable the first time, so you don't have to repeat the query.

Comment: I means as saved or cache a data after random from sql database on any page. Normally, it would be dynamic randomly eqch time when load page.